# Running an SDL executable on OS X that was compiled in windows 8

Tags: macos, sdl

I want to make my SDL executable run on OS X although I am not sure how as I'm unfamiliar with it. I'm using SDL 2 and code::blocks 6 as my IDE. Using the .exe in the bin folder along with the proper DLL's and images (For the sprites). The .exe file will run on my machine with no problems. However, when I send all of the files to my friend who is running os X it does not run. according to her, it gets a lot of gibberish.

Is there anything I should do when compiling to make the .exe OS X compatible. In addition, is there anything my friend should do on her end. We are working collaboratively on a game (She is doing art and I a doing programming), but we are thousands of miles apart. So I  have to give her easy to follow instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Windows binaries and OS X binaries are not compatible.

The only way to run the binary on OS X is to either compile an OS X binary version of it or to have your friend use Parallels or BootCamp to run Windows, and then run your app there.

Even if you could make it run, there's no expectation that it would work on OS X. If you're going to develop for a different OS, you need a system that you can use to test and debug your app on that operating system.

Comment: Can you compile an OS X compatible binary in Windows?

Comment: @ElliottMiller: I don't use CodeBlocks, so I don't know the answer to that question. The executable and DLLs used in Windows are not usable on OS X, and that was the question you asked here. Even if you could make it run, you'd still need to be able to test and debug it, and for that you need a system running OS X. You can't just assume it will work the same on different operating systems.